# How to get objectId from Parse.com rest api in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am working on a project using Parse.com rest api and Ionic/angularjs.

When I issue a Post request, I would like to get the objectId from the Response body.

I can see that the objectId is included in the response in json format, but I can´t seem to extract it.

```
var signUp = new SignUp(signUpData);

var response = signUp.$save(); // using angularjs $resource
console.log(response);
```

When I log the reponse I get this in the console: Object { $$state: Object }
"Dotting" into $$state only returns a number.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  never used Parse.com but if you are using $resource code below should works

```
var signUp = new SignUp(signUpData);

signUp.$save(function(response){

console.log(response);
});
```